# Refresh / Redraw Datatables over function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

and i call the datatable over the function.
Here is my function :

```
function drawTable(yearParameter) {
            var oTable = $('#horizontal-monthly').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url : '{!! route('adm1n.laporan-bulanan-data') !!}',
                    data : function (d) {
                        d.year = yearParameter;
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                  { data: 'B_01', name: 'B_01', sortable: false },
                  { data: 'B_02', name: 'B_02', sortable: false }
                ],
                dom : '<"dt-panelmenu clearfix"lr>t<"dt-panelfooter clearfix"ip>',
            });
        }
```

And i have event `change` to call my function above and pass parameter on it.
How to reload the datatables? Cause right now datatables won't reload.

I try to use :

```
oTable.destroy();
oTable.draw();
```

It make datatables functionality not work. Like search, pagination etc.

> **Edit**
>   Here is my `change` event :

```
$('#year-value').on('change', function(e) {
      var yearParam = $('#year-value').val();
      drawTable(yearParam);
});
```

How to handle that?

Thank you??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
oTable.clear();
oTable.draw();
```

Also, can I see your change event? I can help you re-add the rows

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, you can't call DT constructor more than once. First thing what you want to do is to save DT object as global object.

```
function drawTable() {
  if(!oTable)
  {
        oTable = $('#horizontal-monthly').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url : '{!! route('adm1n.laporan-bulanan-data') !!}',
                data : function (d) {
                    d.year = filterYearParam;
                }
            },
            columns: [
              { data: 'B_01', name: 'B_01', sortable: false },
              { data: 'B_02', name: 'B_02', sortable: false }
            ],
            dom : '<"dt-panelmenu clearfix"lr>t<"dt-panelfooter clearfix"ip>',
        });
    }
 }
 else
 {
      oTable.ajax.reload().draw();
 }

$('#year-value').on('change', function(e) {
  filterYearParam = $('#year-value').val();
  drawTable();
});
```

Try this, and then I can try making your year to work.

Comment: ok this should work. Moved out DT and year objects to globals

Comment: This is defently the way to go. @fanjavaid, both `oTable` and `filterYearParam` should be global variables.